# How to define my DB relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

We have the following (part) models.

```
User
Booking
Apartment
Villa
Bed_Breakfast
Boutique_hotel
```

The user can have many bookings and a booking can have many villas, apartments, B&B or boutique hotels.

This is my idea to set up the relationships.

```
class User 
 has_many: bookings
end

class booking
 belons_to :user
end

class Apartment
 belongs_to :booking
end

class Villa
 belongs_to :booking
end
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Thanks...

remco

Comment: How can one booking can have multiple villas, apartments and all? It seems confusing.

Comment: there are situations that a customer books ....2 apartments. Week 2 appartent A and week Week 3 apartment B. Your suggestion is that the customer has in this case 2 bookings with each one apartment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, your approach is not good. Seems you are looking for `has_many :through` association in your tables. you can have a look into Rails [has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) Docs. you should go like this:

```
class User 
 has_many :apartments, through: bookings
end

class booking
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :apartment
end

class Apartment
 belongs_to :user
 has_one :booking
end
```

Hope it will help. Thanks.

Comment: User directly not associated with apartment, with this relationship user table will not have apartment_id, nor apartment will have user_id, there should always be a booking entry for each apartment per user.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah everything looks good and add this

```
class booking
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :villas
 has_many :apartments
 ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Villa and Apartment seem to be the same thing. Are they not both a `Property`? You could have a `Property` to keep yourself DRY (don't repeat yourself) which would eliminate writing the same code for each of the Apartments/Villas. My recommendation is this:

```
class Villa < Property < ActiveRecord::Base
end 

class Apartment < Property < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Alternatively you could use a Polymorphic Design and have a property type.